# Hide the specific column in Print Page c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview, print-preview

I want to hide the column in the print page.

Here is the image that shows the `ID` column is still visible:

[image]

I want to hide the `ID` column.

Here is the code that i am using, I have already declared `this.dataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false` , but the `ID` column is still visible.

```
private void PrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog _PrintPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            _PrintPreview.Document = printDocument1;
            ((Form)_PrintPreview).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            _PrintPreview.ShowDialog();

            this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
        }

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                strFormat = new StringFormat();
                strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

                arrColumnLefts.Clear();
                arrColumnWidths.Clear();
                iCellHeight = 0;
                iRow = 0;
                bFirstPage = true;
                bNewPage = true;

                iTotalWidth = 0;

                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Set the left margin
                int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;

                //Set the top margin
                int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;

                //Whether more pages have to print or not
                bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;

                int iTmpWidth = 0;

                int width = 500;

                int height = 90;

                //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
                if (bFirstPage)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    {
                        iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width / (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth * ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                        iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                        // Save width and height of headres
                        arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                        arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                        iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                    }
                }

                //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
                while (iRow <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow GridRow = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow];

                    //Set the cell height
                    iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;

                    int iCount = 0;

                    //Check whether the current page settings allo more rows to print
                    if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                    {
                        bNewPage = true;
                        bFirstPage = false;
                        bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (bNewPage)
                        {
                            //Draw Header
                            e.Graphics.DrawString("Database Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("Database Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                            String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

                            //Draw Date
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Regular), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("Database Summary", new Font(new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Regular), FontStyle.Regular), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                            //Draw Image
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb1.Image, new Rectangle(300, 0, width, height));

                            //Draw Columns    
                            iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;

                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua), new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);

                                iCount++;
                            }

                            bNewPage = false;
                            iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                        }

                        iCount = 0;

                        //Draw Columns Contents                
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                        {
                            if (Cel.Value != null)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue), new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                            }

                            //Drawing Cells Borders 
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                            iCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    iRow++;
                    iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
                }

                //If more lines exist, print another page.
                if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Any help how do i fix this?

Thank you!

Your answer will be great appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in `printDocument1_PrintPage`:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua), new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);

    iCount++;
}
```

You are looping over **ALL** columns and printing thier values. So you should skip the ID column. Keep in mind that changing particular column `Visible` property to false will not hide it from the `dataGridView1.Columns` collection.

Anyway, one easy way to achieve your goal:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (GridCol.Name != "ID")
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua), new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);

        iCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. But i got one more problem, the column ID is gone, but the ID number is still there, like this image: (i uploaded to the dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxagdwujkma3kb0/Capture.PNG

Thank you

Comment: @Kaoru Do the same for: `foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)` you should filter the cells that belong to the ID column. (you can check for `Cel.ColumnIndex` for example). Consider redesign of your logic.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will consider redesign my logic of this print page :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your this line **this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;** as the first line of your **PrintPreview** method, because when you call **_PrintPreview.ShowDialog();** will call **printDocument1_BeginPrint** and hence that column is visible.

Comment: In your printing logic where you have displayed all columns try to check for invisible columns and try it.

Answer (score 1):

As Mo.Ashfaq already answered, you have a logical mistake here

```
    private void PrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        _PrintPreview.ShowDialog();

        this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
    }
```

make it this way

```
    private void PrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
        _PrintPreview.ShowDialog();
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = true; // restore visibility
    }
```

next thing is what setting column invisible doesn't prevent from enumerating it (as etaiso answered), replace all occurrences

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    ...
}
```

with

```
foreach (var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    if(column.Visible)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try not having the parameter of the ID column at all to visible being false or true.

But as etaiso said you are looping through all the columns when you execute your loop through all the rows.

All you need to do is this change

```
                int iCount = 0;
```

to

```
                int iCount = 1;
```

that way you skip the first column in your for loop and the ID column, column 0 won't appear in your print preview